# Why do the Kage's have animals in the background?

Tags: naruto

I think the animals are supposed to represent some kind of virtue, but I'm not sure what.
Is there any explanation on why those specific animals were chosen?

[image: Hokage]
[image: Raikage]
[image: Mizukage]
[image: Kazekage]

Comment: Hmm and Tsunade doesn't have a slug behind her..

Comment: And Madara's is a cannon :D

Comment: where is old man tsuchikage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across this on a [forum](http://narutobase.net/forums/showthread.php?t=353407).. I could find no other references but for the most part, it makes sense somewhat.

> 1. Gaara is the young buffalo with keen instincts and promise.
> 2. Tsunade is the rampant moose that charges without hesitation.
> 3. Raikage is the bear that holds dominance and power on top of everyone.
> 4. Mei is the whale that protects the sea (her village)
> 5. Tsuchikage is the ancient scripture, the scripture that possesses much knowledge and experience.

Comment: hmm.. that makes sense. I was hoping for something a bit more concrete. I'll hold off on marking this as an answer for another week or two to see if anyone can come up with some references.

Comment: could you please provide some facts rather than the reference in the forum?

Comment: we can't make any astute assumptions like that...... they show many random things........ i remembered  in one of the song where Naruto,Sai and Sakura combine their power by performing some random seals........but those are just some arbitary stuff........i don't think there is any metaphor associated to it.........

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you been thinking that this could be a random thing? Because on the first answer, the animals doesn't seem to reflect much of the person even if they make some sense. But in this case, why isn't Tuschikage's picture here, too?

Comment: it do see random, but the explanation given does fit in somehow.